# How should I end an if-else block, if any other input means something went wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

In Python3, I'm evaluating blackjack cards represented as chars.

```
for card in hand:
        if card.isdigit():
            result += int(str)
        elif card == "X":
            result += 10
        elif card == "A":
            result += 11
            num_aces += 1
        else:
            #Something went wrong.
            #What should I put here?
```

What kind of error/exception should I throw, if any? Or what is a good convention when all other input is unacceptable?

Comment: There are many ways to approach this, and you have not provided enough information to decide what is the best approach (you are going to get opinions). Firstly, can it actually happen that you have a card not in the list, if not just don't put an `else:` clause. You can `return` an Error, you can `raise` an Exception, you can `print/log` a message and ignore. You have not provided enough to narrow it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for card in hand:
        if card.isdigit():
            result += int(str)
        elif card == "X":
            result += 10
        elif card == "A":
            result += 11
            num_aces += 1
        else:
            #Something went wrong.
            raise ValueError("Illegal card")
```

Give your Exception a meaningful description to make it self documenting since they are expected to be exceptional cases.

Comment: Much appreciated, makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own exception, and raise it:

```
class InvalidCard(ValueError):
    pass

(...)

for card in hand:
    if card.isdigit():
        result += int(str)
    elif card == "X":
        result += 10
    elif card == "A":
        result += 11
        num_aces += 1
    else:
        raise InvalidCard(card + " is invalid")
```

Comment: `InvalidCard` should probably inherit from a subclass of `Exception`, since `Exception` is very generic.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw a `ValueError`, since the value is invalid. In that case, you may want to check the type first and throw a `TypeError` if it is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate if the input is valid first, and then proceed to the statements.
You can even extract it in a function to make it cleaner.

Also, I think this if else statements better translate to a switch statement.

```
#meta code
for card in hand:
  if(!card.isDigit() && card !== "X" && card !== "Y") {
    // Throw your exception
  }
  #proceed to switch statement
```